# New printer won't read files from SD card

Tags: creality-ender-3

I have a new Ender 3 V2 printer that I assembled. The printer reads the TF/SD stock card info but won't read the auto-level code I downloaded. It doesn't even show up on the card.

I downloaded auto-level code and the printer won't read that code, other than the factory-installed code that came with the printer. I formatted the SD card per advice but still no reading of the card by the printer.

This is my first 3D printer and I am not very tech-savvy but I think I've done everything right per instructions and descriptions I've seen online.

Comment: What's the file name of the auto level code as you put it on your TF card?  Also, welcome to 3D Printing Stack Exchange!  Please take the [tour] and read over the [FAQ] -- it'll help you ask better questions and write better answers.

Comment: ender+3+bed+level(1)zip

Comment: from thingiverse

Comment: I purchased a cr touch auto bed leveling sensor and from what i have researched I will need to download another gcode to run that sensor. if my printer wont read new gcodes that's due to be delivered today I am quite worried I wont be able to use the  the new sensor . Thank you for the welcome.

Comment: Your printer doesn't know how to read a .zip file.  It can only execute .gcode (or in the case of flashing new firmware, .bin or possible .hex).

Comment: I have edited your post because it was difficult to understand what exactly is going on. Please [edit] additional information that can help you with the problem. If you see anything that needs to be changed, please do so.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure your SD card is formatted to FAT32.
- The printer can only understand files on the SD card that
  are `.gcode` or `.bin` . In your case, you will need to flash the
  pre-compiled firmware as a `.bin` file.
- Make sure the file is named `firmware.bin` and that it is the right
  firmware for your 3D printer. **It will not work if it is still in a
  `.zip` or `.rar` archive.**
- I do not own an Ender 3 V2 myself, but from experience, the screen may
  stay blank for around 5 seconds while the motherboard updates when you reboot the printer. If
  your printer does this while it updates, it can be a good way to tell
  if your firmware update worked.
- On the LCD navigate the UI to find the `Restore Defaults` button.